# Using Java Set in FreeMarker

Tags: java, freemarker

From my Java code I am returning `Set` of `Address` class objects... Now in FreeMarker I want to display the value of all this `Address` class objects values..

My Java Class

```
public class Address  implements java.io.Serializable {
private String phone;
private String landLineNumber;

  public Address() {}

  public String getPhone() {
    return this.phone;
  }

  public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  public String getLandLineNumber() {
    return this.landLineNumber;
  }

  public void setLandLineNumber(String landLineNumber) {
    this.landLineNumber = landLineNumber;
  }
```

in FreeMarker I am doing following

```
[#list addList as ${setaddress!''} Phone : ${addList.phone!''}<br/>
Land Line : ${addList.landLineNumber!''}
[/#list]
```

Now I am getting the error while populating so is it the correct way???

Comment: You talk about freemarket but added a tag about freemarker. You probably made an error either way.

Comment: Ya..that was my mistake to be in hurry...I mean the Freemarker(ftl) by that..

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: You have to be complete. When you say error, what is the error?

Comment: @adarshr there is no point of it as ftl is simply gives filenotfound exception in any error... its the error from view side...

Comment: Then something is wrong with the Web application framework you are using, because FreeMarker doesn't just report `FileNotFoundError` for a syntactically wrong template like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copy-pasted your template properly here? Because it looks weird. It should be something like:

```
[#list addList as add]
  ${setaddress!''} Phone : ${add.phone!''}<br/>
  Land Line : ${add.landLineNumber!''}
[/#list]
```

Also, if you don't get any meaningful error message, just a `FileNotFoundError`, something is wrong with the integration of FreeMarker there...